# about maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don`t understand “if $x∉J$ then $J ⊂ x+J$. Please explain me and show me that every element of $J$ is in $x+J$.

$J$ be a maximal ideal and suppose $xy$ is in $J$. We want to show either $x$ is in $J$ or $y$ is in $J$. Well if $x$ is in $J$ then we are done. So suppose $x$ is not in $J$. Then $(x)+J$ is an ideal properly containing $J$. By maximality, $(x)+J = R$. So $1$ is in $(x)+J$, which means $1 = ax + b$ for some $a$ in $R$ and $b$ in $J$. Then $y = yax + yb = axy + yb$. Now $b$ is in $J$ so $yb$ is in $J$. And $xy$ is in $J$ so $axy$ is in $J$. Thus $y = axy + yb$ is in $J$.

Comment: I suspect the inclusion is (meant to be) $J\subset (x) + J$, where $(x) + J$ is the sum of the principal ideal generated by $x$ and $J$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to say: $J\subset x+J$ is not true for $x\not\in J$. It must be $J\subset (x)+J$.

Comment: show me that every element of J is in (x)+J

Comment: Alternatively $\ x,y\not\in J\,\Rightarrow\,(J,x) = (1) = (J,y)\,\Rightarrow\, 1 \in (J,x)(J,y)\!\overset{xy\,\in\, J}\subset\!\!\! J,\,$ contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $j \in J$.  Then $0\in (x)$, so $j=0+j \in (x) + J$.